# Day count function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm experiencing an issue calculating the number of days between two given dates.
In my case I have a date for a credit application and another date for credit approval and I need to calculate the number of days between these dates.
All ok here.
I'm struggling with the situation where there isn't a credit approval yet and then I get a negative number.
In this situation I would need to calculte the days elapsed since the credit application.
I believe I would need to combine two formulas but I cannot seem find out how.

thank you in advance if you give me a hint

Mario

Comment: What about `=IF(A1-B1<0, ..., ...)`

Comment: number of days between two given dates  ->> days() function in excel.. right?

Comment: Start date in A1, approval date in B1:  `=DATEDIF($A1,IF($B1="",TODAY(),$B1),"d")+1` or `=IF($B1="",TODAY(),$B1)-$A1+1`.... if B1 is empty use todays date, else use B1.